# How to run Python Azure SDK in a Github Actions workflow with federated credentials authentication

Tags: python, azure, federated-identity, azure-sdk

I have a Python tool that wants to interact with Azure SDK (list and upload blobs). Typically I would use something like:

```py
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

creds = DefaultAzureCredential()
client = BlobServiceClient(..., credential=creds)
```

Considering that I am relying on the Authentication to be via the current logged in user in the CLI, I would like to run this script in a GitHub Action workflow.

The catch is that the authentication method in the GitHub action **MUST** be via federated credentials.

I have a service principal with the federated identity configured, I can authenticate and login using the `azure/login` action. The problem is that in the step where the Python script must be run, it seems that the context of the logged-in CLI from the previous step is not carried over because I see the following error:

```bash
azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
```

My workflow looks like this (simplified):

```yaml
jobs:
  execute:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      # checkout and other stuff
      # ...

      - name: AZ Login
        uses: Azure/login@v1
        with:
          client-id: ${{ vars.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}
          subscription-id: ${{ vars.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
          tenant-id: ${{ vars.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}

      # setup python and install packages
      # ...

      - name: Run script
        run: |
          .venv/bin/python script.py
```

Quetion is: how can I propagate the credentials from the `azure/login` step into the python runtime environment?

Answer (score 0):

```
This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
```

If the service principal doesn't have permissions to read or perform the operations, you will get the above error. To resolve the error add `storage data contributor`  role to the service principle to blob storage account as follows:
Step1: Go to IAM of storage account, click on `Add` and select  `Add role assignment` as shown below:

[image]

Step2: Search for  `storage data contributor`  role and select it as shown below:

[image]

Step3: Select the service principle as mentioned below:

[image]

After successful role assignment you will be able to read file or list the files in container using below code:

```
import io
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import pandas as pd
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential

account_url = "https://<storageAccountName>.blob.core.windows.net"
container_name = "<containerNmae>"
file_path = "<filePath>"
TENANT_ID = "<tenantId>"
CLIENT_ID = "clientId"
CLIENT_SECRET = "clientSecret"
credentials = ClientSecretCredential(TENANT_ID, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=account_url, credential=credentials)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
blobs_list = container_client.list_blobs()
for blob in blobs_list:
    print(blob.name)
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(file_path) 
blob_data = blob_client.download_blob()
csv_data = blob_data.content_as_text()
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_data))
print("Sample.CSV data:")
print(df)
```

[image]

Comment: The service principal does have the permission and that use case is not equivalent as I am using federated credentials rather than cliend id + client secret

Comment: You can check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/github/connect-from-azure?tabs=azure-portal%2Clinux#use-the-azure-login-action-with-openid-connect) once.